# Android Opengl ES: GLUtils.glTexImage2D causing GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a simple textured quad on Android 2.2 using `GLSurfaceView`. I'm loading a BMP image (128x128) with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` - this seems to work. But whenever I try to put this bitmap into an OpenGL texture using `GLUtils.glTexImage2D` I get an OpenGL error: `glGetError()` returns 1280, `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code for my Renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Context context;
    int texId;

    public MyRenderer(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        this.texId = loadTexture(gl);       
    }

    int loadTexture(GL10 gl) {      
        int[] tmp = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, tmp, 0);
        int id = tmp[0];

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
        gl.glGetError();
        GLUtils.texImage2D(id, 0, bmp, 0);
        int err = gl.glGetError();
        if (err != 0) {
            // err == 1280, prints "invalid enum":
            System.err.println(GLU.gluErrorString(err));
        }

        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {      
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, height, 0);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should probably be something like:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
```